# I have a method that takes timezone name as a parameter and gives the current date's day component. But it gives different incorrect results

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents, nstimezone

Suppose i have two parameters

Australia/Sydney (GMT+10) offset 36000 & 
Asia/Kolkata (IST) offset 19800

as timezones, it gives different values for the day component of current day itself. I am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong.. :( A little clue will be appreciated

```
-(NSInteger)getDayWithTimeZoneName:(NSString *)timeZoneName{

    // Instantiate a timezone
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneName];

    //Instantiate a date formatter
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [df setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateStr];
//    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    NSInteger day = [components day];

    NSLog(@"Date component for timeZone %@ is %ld", timeZoneName,(long)day);
    return day;
}
```

Comment: "it gives different values for the day component of current day" Isn't that expected for certain times of the day?

Comment: I am confused at this thing. If i run this code for say two different time zones at the very same day. [NSDate date]. How can it give different value for day component? For this ( Asia/Kolkata) timezone i am getting day component = 16, and for Australia/Sydney i am getting day component =15

Comment: It probably relates to `[NSDate date]` as that will be the current date/time in the GMT timezone (`NSDate` doesn't have a timezone).

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, since `NSDate` "doesn't have timezones" (correctly: time has no timezones), `[NSDate date]` cannot be in the GMT timezone as you said. Timezones are completely unrelated to time.

Comment: @AmitMajumdar You can have different day values, if somewhere between the locations it is midnight. You should add a concrete example to your Q including GMT (via `NSLog()`) and the two locations and its time including day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSFormatter isn't designed to convert or calculate dates:

```
NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

`dateStr` is the date in Sydney (2016-05-16 0:00).

```
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateStr];
```

`date` is GMT, 10 hours behind Sydney (2016-05-15 14:00).

Use NSCalendar to calculate dates:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = timeZone;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [components day];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)